# Clear recurring events from calendar during vacation?

Tags: google-calendar

I have lots of recurring events on my calendar. I want to clear my calendar during my vacation. My solution so far has been:

1. select the first instance of recurring event "A" after the vacation starts;
2. figure out when it will recur after I return, reschedule it for that date, and select "Reschedule this and future events"
3. repeat for events "B"-"Z", which is cumbersome.

Is there a way to select multiple events at once and delete "this occurrence"?